# UIAlertController code runs, but doesn't present an alert

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to make an in-app popup alert using swift and I have run into an error that I know nothing about.

Here is the code I use to present my alert:

```
let welcomeAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Welcome!", message: “message here”, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
welcomeAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
self.presentViewController(welcomeAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

println("welcome alert displayed!")
```

The error I'm getting back says this:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7b89a950> on <MyApp.RootClientViewController: 0x7aea8fb0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

This is immediately followed by a printed statements stating `welcome alert displayed!`.

So my code is certainly running, but for some reason, it won't display the alert...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did u run it in a playground?

Comment: @AnthonyKong no, but it is inside the `viewDidLoad` method if that helps...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you the answer: *"view is not in the window hierarchy!"* means `self.view` is not on screen when the call is made (technically it means `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow` is not an ancestor of `self.view`).

Usually this happens when presenting a view controller in `viewDidLoad()` or `viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)`. Wait for `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)`, present from `UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window.rootViewController` or present from `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow.rootViewController`.

Comment: The problem is trying to present a view controller from a view controller which is not on screen. You can check this with `self.view. isDescendantOfView(UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow)`. Whenever this is `true`, you can present a view controller.

Comment: Oh okay! So I'd just put that code in an if statement to check if I can present my alert?

Comment: Let me back up here, normally the test is not needed. You need to know the view controller's lifecycle (specifically, what parts run on screen and what parts run off screen). From `viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)` up until `viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool)` are all on screen. Anything else is off screen.